# Mailbox is full, how do I delete items from the server?

Tags: exchange, office365

Emails have been deleted locally but if I check the file size of the folders in my inbox Local data is a few megabytes but server data is many gigabytes. How do remove the emails from the server?

Comment: WHICH version of Exchange server is in use? Instructions will vary. Please click [edit] and specify that, In Your Question, Not In Comments. As per Microsoft's Manage mailbox databases in Exchange Server, don't permanently delete items until the database has been backed up: Select this check box to prevent mailboxes and email messages from being deleted until after the mailbox database has been backed up.   Twice.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/mailbox-servers/manage-databases?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long has it been since you deleted items?

In Exchange Server, when a user deletes items from the Deleted Items default folder, the items are moved to the Recoverable Items\Deletions folder. The duration that deleted items remain in this folder is based on the deleted item retention settings configured for the mailbox database or the mailbox. By default, a mailbox database is configured to retain deleted items for 14 days, and the recoverable items warning quota and recoverable items quota are set to 20 gigabytes (GB) and 30 GB respectively.

You could use the Exchange admin center (EAC) to configure deleted item retention for the mailbox, and purge the items in the recoverable Items folder. After that, check the mailbox storage again.

**Configure Deleted Item retention and Recoverable Items quotas**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/deleted-item-retention-and-recoverable-items-quotas?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also delete your deleted items. You can login to [webmail](https://outlook.office365.com) and see what the server currently has, optionally deleting the mails there. Make sure your outlook syncs too.